# What is the limit of the Farscape communication ("comms") device?

Tags: technology, farscape, communication

The [Farscape Wiki](http://farscape.wikia.com/wiki/Communication_device) says:

> "Comms or communication devices were integrated systems connected to
>   and controlled by Leviathans such as Moya.
>
> The devices had a fairly wide range, but a distinct limit. Portable
>   units could be attached to clothing and used to communicate with other
>   portable devices in addition to the Leviathan and her Pilot."

-- but it doesn't say what the limit is or have any references to their justification of that. I was sure that they were FTL communication but can't recall why.

Answer (score 2):

Moya's ship's comms appear to be (at best) interplanetary. On several occasions ([I-Yensch, You-Yensch](http://transcripts.terrafirmascapers.com/319.htm), ['Til The Blood Runs Clear](http://transcripts.terrafirmascapers.com/111.htm) ) we see people being described as 'out of range' while conducting deep space recons or on other planets within the same system.

> **D'Argo:** (indicating the heavy mist outside the view port) *Aeryn went out into that and we haven't heard from her since. Perhaps you
>   sensed the danger and that's what woke you.*
>
> **Zhaan:** *How long's she been gone?*
>
> **John:** *One solar day. Thought we'd hide in this fog - or whatever it is
>   - from the Peacekeepers. Aeryn went on long-range recon and she hasn't come back yet.*
>
> **Zhaan:** *No signal from her?*
>
> **John:** *Nothing.* (but at that moment - something)
>
> **Aeryn:** (via comm, the signal is wobbly) *Moya, is that you?*

I've seen no evidence that the comms are FTL although the usual trope of being able to [instantly communicate](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SubspaceAnsible?from=Main.FTLRadio) regardless of distance *does* apply.

Comment: For the record, FTL communication does exist in Farscape. We see both the Skarans and Peacekeeper Command communicating over great distances instantly. But that isn't within the scope of the question.

Comment: Can you provide an example of immediate or instant communications between PKC or Skarans at vast distances? I only remember them saying "send a message" without any clear indication of how long that takes. I also don't remember seeing any real-time communications over long distances. For example, when Crais receives his order to abandon his chase (which he summarily ignores) it comes on some kind of recording, rather than live.

Comment: @Polynomial - That's true, but if the communication was at light-speed, there's no possible way it could have got there; http://transcripts.terrafirmascapers.com/108.htm.

Comment: You're precluding the possibility that the chip was physically delivered, since the ships seem to be capable of FTL travel. I'll agree that it would be odd, though.

Comment: @Polynomial -  In [Nerve](http://transcripts.terrafirmascapers.com/119.htm), Scorpius directs his people to "*Broadcast a wide-dispersal message, coded to Crais' Command Carrier*".

Comment: Ah yes. Nice cite!